# change background color of row in jtable after selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to create a `TableCellRenderer` which changes the background of row. I am overriding the `prepareRenderer`, it changes the background of row on selection but as soon as I change the selection the default background color(white) is set to previous selected row and newer row gets the background color(light grey).

Here is my code:

> ```
> final JTable table = new JTable(model)
>     {
>             @Override
>         public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,int row,int column)
>         {
>             Component comp=super.prepareRenderer(renderer,row, column);
>            int modelRow=convertRowIndexToModel(row);
>            if(!isRowSelected(modelRow))
>                comp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
>            else
>                comp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
>            return comp;
>         }
>     };
> ```

My output screen:

[image]

I want to do like this:

[image]

Comment: How do you determine of a row was previously selected?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will set a specific value or flag in db so that whenever user click on mail. On refresh I will check for those flags which user selected previously.

Comment: Some cell renderers may also be transparent...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't understand what did you said

Comment: Some cell renders may be transparent, meaning that changing here background color won't actually have any effect...just saying ;)

Comment: you have to store values from selections in ListSelectionModel, a few times here, as aside your "output screen" showing more complicated things than simple workaround by playing with selection and to store this/those value(s) in ListSelectionModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you can do the following:

IN your model keep a hidden column of flag values. Assume that your hidden column is 5 column and you can code as below:

```
final JTable table = new JTable(model)
    {
            @Override
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,int row,int column)
        {
            Component comp=super.prepareRenderer(renderer,row, column);
           int modelRow=convertRowIndexToModel(row);
           if((Boolean)getValueAt(row,5))
               comp.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
           else
               comp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
           return comp;
        }
    };
```

Your flag values contain the Boolean object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new TableCellRenderer(){
        private DefaultTableCellRenderer DEFAULT_RENDERER =  new DefaultTableCellRenderer();


            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component c = DEFAULT_RENDERER.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                //table.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                 //table.setSelectionBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                if(isSelected){
                    c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                }else{
                if (row%2 == 0){
                    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                }
                else {
                    c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                }     }

                return c;
            }

        });
```

Comment: Not sure the OP was really after candy stripping ;)

Comment: Jugadu your code will work same as me it will just shows the selected row in Yellow color and striping color in `JTABLE` which I don't want to I want to keep the background color of row after selection also.